# How to build p2 repository with p2-maven-plugin and use local directory as a source of JARs?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, dependency-management, tycho

Situation: Eclipse RCP application using `Maven Tycho plugin`, now I want to integrate properly p2-maven-plugin`. I have a directory containing all 3rd party JARs and Eclipse plugins as JARs.

How to use `p2-maven-plugin` to create p2 repository which includes all files from this directory?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>p2-site</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
                <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
<!--   How can I get there artifacts located in directory on my local machine??? These libs (in example below) are taken from .m2 maven repo  -->
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4</id>
                                </artifact>
                                <artifact>
                                    <id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.5</id>
                                </artifact>
                                <artifact>
                                    <id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6</id>
                                </artifact>
                                <artifact>
                                    <id>junit:junit:3.8.2</id>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>

                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/repository/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/site</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <stopKey/>
                    <stopPort/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Folder with plugins (JARs) from which I want to generate p2 repository.
[image]

usage of tycho extras p2 plugin in my master pom - doesn't work, I think maybe this piece of code is not called at all... How can I it call?
[image]

Comment: This can be done via the [Tycho p2 Extras plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-extras/tycho-p2-extras-plugin/plugin-info.html)'s [`publish-features-and-bundles`](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-extras/tycho-p2-extras-plugin/publish-features-and-bundles-mojo.html) goal. See [for example here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/master/mirror-non-p2/pom.xml#L53-L66).

Comment: @howlger sorry but it doesn't work, see EDIT above

Comment: `<sourceLocation>` is the directory that contains the `plugins` and `features` folders, not its parent. The screenshot shows that you are still limiting yourself to an IDE without Eclipse support and that you are using Eclipse 3.7.2 which is almost ten years behind. This hurts just watching.