# How to include to local p2-site non JAR file with p2-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2

Old Eclipse RCP project (2010-2012), Maven Tycho, for building local p2 site I use `p2-maven-plugin`. Including artifacts from maven repository works fine, but I didn't find the way how to add to this local p2-site non JARs (non java files as plugins). See in code below:

My p2-site `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>p2-site</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
                <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4</id>
                                </artifact>
                                <artifact>
                                    <id>org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core:2.1.1.v20120113-1346
                                    </id>
                                </artifact>
                                ...
                             </artifacts>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/repository/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/site</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <stopKey/>
                    <stopPort/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Calling `mvn p2:site` creates p2-site with structure showed below and `mvn jetty:run` makes them locally available for my feature.xml file. To this point everything works fine.

```
sarka@ubuntu:~/Git/SPL/spl/p2-site/target/repository$ ll
total 36
drwxrwxr-x 3 sarka sarka  4096 May 12 09:49 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 sarka sarka  4096 May 12 09:49 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sarka sarka  2603 May 12 09:49 artifacts.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sarka sarka   306 May 12 09:49 category.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sarka sarka 14804 May 12 09:49 content.jar
drwxrwxr-x 2 sarka sarka  4096 May 12 09:49 plugins/
```

My `feature.xml` file contains plugins which is not packaged as JAR, eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="my.project.client.feature"
      label="client"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier"
      provider-name="my company"
      os="win32"
      ws="win32"
      nl="cs_CZ"
      arch="x86_64">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
   </license>
    ...
   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>
    ...
```

This fonts plugin looks this way:

```
sarka@ubuntu:~/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts_3.7.2.v20120213$ ll
total 124
drwxrwxr-x  3 sarka sarka  4096 Mar 16 11:20 ./
drwxrwxr-x 38 sarka sarka 86016 Apr 23 10:39 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarka sarka  1433 Mar 16 11:20 about.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarka sarka   721 Mar 16 11:20 fontsConfig_linux.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarka sarka  1606 Mar 16 11:20 fontsConfig_pdf.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarka sarka   693 Mar 16 11:20 fontsConfig_win32.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarka sarka  9533 Mar 16 11:20 fontsConfig.xml
drwxrwxr-x  2 sarka sarka  4096 Mar 16 11:20 META-INF/
```

My question is - how to add this non-JAR directory to p2 site which is now generated by `p2-maven-plugin`? I read the brief documentation on their [github page](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin) but I didn't find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Same as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67398166/6505250) (`unpack="false"` means it's still a JAR in the p2 repository but a folder when installed) to which you have stopped responding like you did with the three answers before.

Comment: @howlger Sorry I hope that someone else told me something useful, not just "update your eclipse project/don't use intellij/etc."

Comment: How can you say that after adopting my solution? You just specified the wrong `<sourceLocation>`. Using software that is almost a decade old can cause problems (by the way, what is said in the GitHub project you referring is no longer true nor needed for recent Tycho versions). Of course you can use IntelliJ or any other text editor without Eclipse support, but in Eclipse you simply opened the `MANIFEST.MF`  file and click the _Export Wizard_ link for that. If you want to do it with Maven instead, see my comments to your previous question (`MANIFEST.MF` should have `Eclipse-BundleShape: dir`).